# Does any topology-defining set operator distribute over symmetric difference?

Tags: general-topology

A Colloquium Mathematicum problem posed 70 years ago by A. D. Wallace (at the bottom of [this page](http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm2/cm2148.pdf)) asks this question.  A brief search indicates that a solution was probably never published. Does such an operator exist?

Comment: My offhand guess would be the boundary operator but that probably doesn’t work: it would be the first that Wallace tried, I suppose.

Comment: But that fails for $A=(0,1), B=(1,2)$ where $\partial (A \Delta B)=\{0,1,2\} \neq \partial A \Delta \partial B=\{0,2\}$, e.g.